# How to Change the file name downloading from http.get() method | Node js

Tags: node.js, express, http, amazon-s3, http-get

Below I am downloading file from the aws s3,But I want to rename downloaded file to newName.txt

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

let URL = "http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploadedFile.txt"

      http.get(URL,function(file){

        file.pipe(res)

      })
  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,Lets consider ,If you want to download .apk file from the aws .And new file name is newApk.apk then you can use following code

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

let URL = "http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/apkFolderNameInAwsS3"

      http.get(URL,function(file){

      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=newApk.apk');
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.android.package-archive');

        file.pipe(res)

      })
  

});
```

here `'application/vnd.android.package-archive'` mime type for apk file.